# DORA process TCPIP

Tags: dhcp, wireshark

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DHCPGeneralOperationandClientFiniteStateMachine.htm

I'm reading through the entire Discover, Offer, Request, Acknowledgement phases in DHCP. And I am really confused. My confusion lies in what is being sent and received in these packets. I've done wiresharking and still I am confused.

## DHCP Discover.

Source IP=0.0.0.0(Since client doesn't have an IP address)

Destination IP=255.255.255.255(Since destination is broadcast IP address)

Source Ethernet Address=hardware address of client who doesn't yet have an IP

Destination Ethernet Address=All F's(as it's broadcasted to everyone)

## DHCP Offer

Server makes an offer of IP address.

As per wireshark, source IP=IP of DHCP server =10.13.166.0.
Destination IP=IP of client=10.13.166.166(assigned IP). **But that doesn't make any sense as the client yet hasn't got an IP, it's just an offer made.**

source ethernet address=hardware address of DHCP server.

Destination ethernet address=hardware address of client requesting IP.

## DHCP Request

Client broadcasts DHCP request packet.

Source IP=0.0.0.0(client requesting the IP's IP)

Destination IP=255.255.255.255(broadcast IP)

## DHCP Acknowledgement

Server sends/confirms IP to client requesting the IP.

Source IP=IP Of DHCP Server

Destination IP=Assigned IP Of device

Source ethernet address=Hardware address of DHCP server

Destination ethernet address=Hardware address of client requesting IP.

My confusion lies here again, should not the destination IP still be broadcast.

Comment: Please don't change around your question to an entirely new question. Instead, post another question as a new question.